# Is there a way to make a read function for redstone computer ROM in MC Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been creating a Redstone computer in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition. I have finished the ROM itself and the ROM master switch, but I need a read function that works like this:

1. The master switch is flicked.
2. The first byte automatically fires.
3. The next byte can not be transmitted until a “complete” signal is sent to it.
4. The cycle begins again from step 2.